# Dynamic horizontal scroll position is only being set by address bar refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with scrolling the window horizontally to the correct position upon automatic refresh.

What I have is a job schedule on an hour to hour basis, with different machines. Jobs are set to run on a machine, at a certain point in time. I've posted a picture below to help facilitate understanding.

[image]
Each machine is an unordered list, with the li's floated left. Each li that does not represent a job, represents an hour of time. Machines are arranged vertically, while time goes horizontally. The purple ul at the top of the page is the timeline, with date and time, which I gave the ID, 'time'. Each li under #time, I gave them their respective values as their ID. So the li that represents 1/16/16 7:00:00 has an ID of '1/16/16 7:00:00'.

The red line that spans the height of the screen indicates the current time. I gave this the ID 'indicator'.

This screen is posted on a TV out on our plant floor for people to see, and I've used the following code within my html to refresh the screen at a certain rate:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120"/>
```

I'll explain what happens when the page loads, then I will post my front end code.

When the page loads, it resets the page position to 0,0. This was added after I had issues scrolling to the wrong position because of the previous window position. I get the current date and time, and use that to look for the offSet of the #time li that has an ID of the current date, and hour. Once I get that offSet value, I set the left position of the indicator line to the offSet.left value. Then I do calculations to account for the minutes. This sets the indicator line to the appropriate position.

I have set the position of the #time ul to be fixed so it is always visible as the TV screen scrolls vertically to show all machines. Because it's a fixed position, I need to set the left position of the #time ul appropriately, otherwise, it will not line up correctly when I scroll the screen horizontally. I would always see the left most side of the #time ul.

The next part is where I am having issues.

I still have the offSet position stored in the variable that I used to set the position of the indicator line. I use the same value to set how far to scroll the screen horizontally. Then I subtract about 500 pixels so we can see a few hours behind us.

When I press enter from the address bar, all positions are set correctly. But every time the screen refreshes, it only scrolls to the position that it did when it was refreshed from the address bar. The indicator line's position is set correctly though, so as the day goes on, the red line slowly moves to the right, and since we run 24 hours a day, by the next morning, it is off the screen. This requires me twice a day to hook up a keyboard to the computer and manually refresh it from the address bar.

I would have thought that since both the position of the red line and the position of the screen are working off of the same variable, if the red line is working, then so should the horizontal scroll.

I've posted my code below. Forgive any sloppy coding, this is one of my first attempts at Javascript and JQuery. I've tried to comment well, so it makes sense. I hope I have explained everything clearly, and I appreciate any help.

```
<script>        
    $(document).ready(function () {

        window.scroll(0, 0);

        //Set the left position of #time correctly for horizontal scrolling
        var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").css("width");
        $("#time").css("width", wrapperWidth);

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('#time').css({
                'left': parseInt($(this).scrollLeft() * -1)
            });
        });

        //function and loop for scrolling vertically
        function scroll(speed) {
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height() }, speed, function () {
                $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, speed);
            });
        }
        var speed = 19000
        scroll(speed)
        setInterval(function () { scroll(speed) }, (speed * 2) + 5000);

        //Set the #time ul width to the #wrapper width to get the correct offSet positions
        var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
        $("#time").css("width", wrapper.css("width"));

        //span #indicator the height of the document
        $("#indicator").height($(document).height());

        //Get the current date and parse it
        var d = new Date();
        var pos = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-
                2) + "/" + d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2) + " " + d.getHours() +
            ":00:00";

        //find the li of the current date and time
        var li = $("[id='" + pos.toString() + "']");
        //if found
        if (li.length > 0) {
            //get the li's position
            var offset = li.offset();

            //set the red line position and add minutes
            $("#indicator").css("left", (offset.left + (d.getMinutes() / 60) * 50));

            //Add hover functionality to show the current time
            $("#indicator").mouseover(function () {
                var now = new Date().toLocaleString();
                $("#indicator").attr("title", now)
            });
            $("#indicator").mouseleave(function () {
                $("#indicator").removeAttr("title")
            });

            //Scroll the screen horizontally to the position of the #time li, minus x pixels
            window.scroll(offset.left - 500, 0);
        //If #time li not found, don't show red line or scroll the screen
        } else {
            $("#indicator").css("display", "none");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue lies with this bit of code.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120"/>
```

The 'refresh' tag is refreshing the page to its 'view-before-refresh', over-riding the custom javascript you have for scrolling the window.

Try commenting that part out and inserting this to the bottom of your Javascript.

```
// update every 120 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.url(<URL_TO_YOUR_SITE>);
}, 120000)
```

Comment: That seemed to have done the trick. I appreciate your quick response, and well laid out answer. Thank you for your help.